# how to use eof in a for loop with iterating integer c++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, eof

this gives me a segmentation fault:

```
for (int i=0; !file.eof();i++)
{
  getline(file,line);
  roughInput.lines[i].split(line);
}
```

and this doesn't

```
for (int i=0; i<2;i++)
{
  getline(file,line);
  roughInput.lines[i].split(line);
}
```

from my understanding for should increase i by one until the end of file, right?
since i couldn't find much example on i-net, is there a better solution?

Comment: This is a stab in the dark, but maybe the segfault is caused by overindexing `roughInput.lines`. Use a debugger to find exactly when the segfault occurs.

Comment: @suszterpatt, yes the problem occurs because i becomes 1 increment higher then the number of objects in the vector lines[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is probably running one time too many.  `file.eof()` will not return false until after you have tried to read while you are at the end of the file.  You probably want to put the check in between the `getline` call and the `split`:

```
    getline(file, line);
    if (!file.eof())
        roughInput.lines[i].split(line);
```

and fix the loop logic accordingly.

However, a better solution would be to grow `roughInput.lines` dynamically, so that you don't get a seg fault if the file is longer than you expect.

Comment: can't grow dynamically split() compares part of a line to a class. if(!eof) works, thank you

Comment: I also believe that `for (int i = 0; file; i++)` would work (and work for the cases where there is a stream error other that eof).